# Multiple dispatch groups causing crash

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

so I have a function that performs some async tasks in a for loop so i added a dispatch group and everything works good

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

for(apple in fruits) {
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [self randomFunction:^{
                   dispatch_group_leave(group);
               }];
   
};
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   //some tasks
    }];
});

randomFunction:(void(^)(void)completionhandler{
//do pushups
completionhandler();
}
```

The issue is that the random function can be invoked from a different flow while the current loop is running the second code looks like this

```
dispatch_group_t group2 = dispatch_group_create();

for(candies in sweets) {
    dispatch_group_enter(group2);
    [self randomFunction:^{
                   dispatch_group_leave(group2);
               }];
   
};
dispatch_group_notify(group2, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   //some tasks
    }];
});

function:(void(^)(void)completionhandler{
//do jumping jacks
 completionhandler();
}
```

when both flows are triggered simultaneously the app crashes with BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: Unbalanced call to dispatch_group_leave(). ihave double/tripple checked and ther are no unbalanced dipatch_group_leave() calls, and the code works fine as long as only one of the flow is invoked at a time. from what i understand I think group.leave() of 1 case is consuming the group.enter() of other and decrementing the count below zero , but since but both groups are different should this happen?

Comment: Put in some `NSLog()` calls when you enter and leave a group and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: You're correct that each group is independent, so that's not the problem. The above code clearly is not your actual code (since it's not even close to valid ObjC). Somewhere your *actual* code has unbalanced calls. I agree with koen that NSLog is probably your best bet to finding where that is. Just looking at the code likely isn't going to find it for you; you need to run it and see where something is called that you don't expect to be called. (Something you believe to be true is not true. That's what a bug is.)

Comment: I agree with @RobNapier, these kinds or problems/crashes are usually associated with unbalanced, or out-of-order `dispatch_group_enter()`/`dispatch_group_leave()` pairs. Consider using a `@try {} @finally {` to catch any exceptions that your code might throw, and to ensure that `dispatch_group_leave()` gets called in *every* case.

Comment: Keep in mind that while `@try` might be helpful here to find bugs (to add better logging before crashing for example), it is not a production solution. Cocoa is not exception-safe, and ObjC try/catch intentionally does not manage memory correctly under ARC unless you build with `-fobjc-arc-exceptions` (ObjC++ turns this on by default). Even with the flag, weak objects will leak by design. As a rule, it's not practical or intended to write exception-safe ObjC code. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#exceptions

Comment: To reiterate what others have said, the problem is not that you have two different dispatch groups going on concurrently. The problem is simply that in one or the other (or both) that you're calling `leave` more times than you're calling `enter`. Your function must have some path of execution where you're calling the completion handler more than once.